# C# attachments do not show in the RDOAttachment Object

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I am reading the RDOAttachment Object, the .Count Attribute is 0, despite the outlook email has two embedded pictures in an html email.

If have ported the same code from C# to VBA in Outlook and it shows correctly there.

Am I doing someting wrong or is there a bug in the RDOAttachment object?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Include the code you are using with the question, if you are receiving any error do post that too, that will help others to understand your problem more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the Outlook message for the MAPI system (and Redemption) to be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Dmitry, here is some for comments on the code. I initially developed the code in Outlook VBA and than ported it to VS C#, it somehow performs different there.

I have a signed email and I want to remove the signature from the email, once done I remap the attachements. Once I delete the key file from the i_iMAPI secure message the attachements from the i_MAPI mail are gone. That is not the case in VBA.

thoughts how to fix this?

```
        i_iMAPI = i_rdoS.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(i_rdoMessage, true);
        i_MAPI = i_rdoS.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(i_rdoMessage);

        //if signed message remove key file and set MessageClass to standard Message
        if (i_iMAPI.MessageClass == "IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned")
        {
            i_iMAPI.MessageClass = "IPM.Note";
            //remove the key file and make sure it is really key file
            foreach (RDOAttachment att in i_iMAPI.Attachments)
            {
                if (att.DisplayName == "Untitled Attachment")
                {
                    att.Delete();
                }
            }

            //create specific Folder for each sender
            i_FilePath = Folders.StorageFolder + i_MAPI.SenderName;
            i_Folder.CreateFolder(i_FilePath);

            //remapp the attachements from MAPI to iMAPI Message
            foreach (RDOAttachment rdoAtt in i_MAPI.Attachments)
            {
                rdoAtt.SaveAsFile(i_FilePath + @"\" + rdoAtt.FileName);                    
                i_iMAPI.Attachments.Add(i_FilePath + @"\" + rdoAtt.FileName);                    
                i_iMAPI.Attachments[i_iMAPI.Attachments.Count].Hidden = rdoAtt.Hidden;                                        
            }
            //save changes
            i_iMAPI.Save();
        }
```